# K-Nearest Neighbour Classifier

Tags: matlab, knn, confusion-matrix

I followed an example of the MATLAB KNN classifier with 10 fold cross validation, I am lost at the stage of computing the model's performance, Please kindly look at my code below and advice on how i can correctly get the accuracy of my classification in percentage (%), I dont get the cVError = 1-mean(errorMat) part. Secondly, the fitcknn and knn.predict functions were used to train and test the model, I need help on how i'll create my own functions to do the same tasks. Thank you.

```
indices = crossvalind('kfold',labels,10);
confusionMatrix = cell(1,1);
errorMat = zeros(1,10);
for i = 1:10
test = (indices==i);
train = ~test;
knn = fitcknn(data(train,:),labels(train),'NumNeighbors',kVal);
y = knn.predict(data(test,:));
index = cellfun(@strcmp,y,labels(test));
errorMat(i) = sum(index)/length(y);
confusionMatrix{i} = confusionmat(labels(test),y);
end

% Calculate misclassification error
cvError = 1-mean(errorMat);
```

Comment: Calculating classification error is going to be tricky, because you have labels for your ground truth and test data, but when you input your test data into `k`-means, the labels may not correspond, even though there may be the case that the data will be clustered correctly.  For example, you could have a cluster of test points having label 1, but the output of `k`-means could give them all label 3, and technically this would be a "misclassification" error.  As such, I really don't know how you'd be able to determine misclassification error, other than looking into the data and relabeling them.

Comment: This question might be a little better suited for Stack Exchange's Cross Validated forum (you may not have known it existed). That forum (http://stats.stackexchange.com/) specializes in discussing different data analytics, machine learning, and other various concepts that you might be interested in.

Comment: at. AustinA Thanks a lot ! I've signed up there for future questions on this topic. @rayryeng Thanks for your response, although your suggestion is not very clear because you are mentioning 'Kmeans' & Clustering. Here, i am working with just KNN classifier (Supervised learning), i am looking into doing the following; 1: Split data into train & test, 2: build model and train on training data, 3: test model on test data, 4: Compute model's classification accuracy. (How well it performed on my test set).

Comment: OHHHH... I thought you were using `kmeans`.  I misread your question.  I suppose if you wanted to measure classification accuracy, you would take a look at the `k` closest points, and measure the **most frequently** occurring label.  You would use this as the final label.

Comment: @rayryeng Oh i thought as much. i see, Thanks again! i will try this.